# Modify array from multilabel classes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to define a set of classes/labels for multilabel classification with classes 1,2,3 and 4, but are having issues with the array accidentally also includes the following:

multilabel.classes_
array([' ', ',', '1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype=object)

I only want to have 1,2,3,4 as my labels, and can't figure out a way to remove this.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import ast
import seaborn as sns #pip install seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skmultilearn #pip install scikit-multilearn

from preprocessing.transcription_preprocessing import TranscriptionPreprocessor
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\M94969\Desktop\datasets\prod500.csv')

# Define label variable
y = df['tags']

# Make multilabelbinarizer object
#multilabel = MultiLabelBinarizer()
#y = multilabel.fit_transform(y)
#multilabel.classes_
#pd.DataFrame(y,columns=multilabel.classes_)

labelbinarizer = LabelBinarizer()

fit = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(y)

labelbinarizer.classes_

pd.DataFrame(y,columns=labelbinarizer.classes_)

# Turn texts into sparse matrix
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', max_features=1000, max_df=0.50, ngram_range=(1,3))
X = tfidf.fit_transform(df['text'])

tfidf.vocabulary_

# Split data into train/test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

# Build models
sgd = SGDClassifier()
lr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
svc = LinearSVC()

def j_score(y_true, y_pred):
    jaccard = np.minimum(y_true, y_pred).sum(axis=1)/np.maximum(y_true, y_pred).sum(axis = 1)
    return jaccard.mean()*100

def print_score(y_pred, clf):
    print("Clf: ", clf.__class__.__name__)
    print('Jacard score: {}'.format(j_score(y_test,y_pred)))
    print('----')

for classifier in [sgd, lr, svc]:
    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifier)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    print_score(y_pred, classifier)
```

link to subset of data:
https://www.filemail.com/d/whkmmsazgrwzfdp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run:

```
df['tags'].unique()
```

on your sample data the output is as follows:

```
array(['1', '3', '2', '1, 2'], dtype=object)
```

The multitag assignment happens in row 7 of your dataframe:

```
df[df['tags']=='1, 2']
```

results in:

```
             text   TV  Internet    Mobil   Fastnet tags
7   TIL YOUSEE...   1   2   0   0   1, 2
```

If you don't want this binarized you could simply remove the row or assign a single label in your dataframe.

Alternatively you can look at the sklearn [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html?highlight=labelbinarizer#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer) to get labels more in line of what you are looking for:

```
labelbinarizer = LabelBinarizer()

fit = labelbinarizer.fit_transform(y)

labelbinarizer.classes_

# array(['1', '1, 2', '2', '3'], dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I have tried the LabelBinarizer which seems correct in this case, but it doesn't work for my code. Maybe you can spot the error if your have my full code: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210916s7WyaPAf

Comment: Can you post your code here (add it to your question)?

Comment: Yes of course - Its done

Comment: Oh! you need this dataset to test it! --> https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210916WRLkoMTB
and this is the error I get: ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SGDClassifier())
Clf:  SGDClassifier

Comment: You have several issues with your code:
1. your passing y_test into j_score() inside print_score(). This y_test is not defined (I assume that comes from your test data in the link posted above).
2. You are trying to compute the Jaccard score by hand by using strings. This is what the error is referreing to above. I would propose you use the internal [jaccard_score function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html) for the computation.

Comment: I'll try to look into these - thanks for help